# What ever happened to Textmate 2?

Tags: editor, textmate, textmate2

What ever happened to Textmate 2?

Comment: Here's the answer guys: http://wastm2released.com/ :D

Comment: The release candidate has just gone live!

Comment: And now the public alpha is available for everyone with a 1.x (non-bundle) license.  http://blog.macromates.com/2011/textmate-2-0-alpha/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I was almost positive that there was a post to the mailing list within the last 4 months that strongly implied -- or outright stated -- that there'd at least be a beta by summer 2009, but I haven't been able to dig it up, so I'm not sure.

To be honest, I'm not really that concerned about TextMate. Sure, I'd love to see it, because new stuff is always cool; but in my opinion there are only 2 big features missing from TextMate -- split-pane viewing and better undo support -- and I've found I can live without those. TextMate 2 will probably be awesome, but the current TextMate is such a great editor that I'm not anxious for TM2 to come out.

**Update:** A public alpha is [due out](http://blog.macromates.com/2011/whats-next/) by Christmas 2011.

**Update:** A public alpha is now [available](http://blog.macromates.com/2011/textmate-2-0-alpha/)

Comment: For me, a better find/replace dialog, with saved pairs, regex syntax coloring, ala BBEdit is the elephant in the editor.

Comment: Not checking the files on disk whenever the window regains focus would be a huge improvement for me. It's quite painful to edit files over NFS.

Comment: +1 for not checking the files on disk... got bitten by this while editing files over cifs/nfs too many times.

Comment: split-pane viewing and mini map are available on sublime text editor and e text editor has great undo support (branches)!

Comment: Needs:
 -> better find/replace dialog
 -> better brace matching/scope highlighting
 -> word autocomplete w/popup (a la Vim).

Comment: I would kill if it didn't crash and lost my unsaved data a) while browsing ssh with macfusion and it can't set a timestamp and b) crash when macfusion loses a connection. I'd also love to be able to edit the bundles themselves in a textmate window in a more integrated fashion.  And of course split pane, and better autocomplete popup options.

Comment: Announced today: TextMate 2 Alpha this year, before Christmas.  http://blog.macromates.com/2011/whats-next/

Answer (score 15):

From the [wiki](http://wiki.macromates.com/FAQ/TextMate2):

> **Q: Is TextMate 2 still in development, or has it been abandoned?**
>
> TM2 is being actively developed. If this text is still here, that is still the case. (Last updated April 7, 2009. Allan stresses that no release is "around the corner" yet.)

The author, Allan Odgaard, has updated the TextMate blog with [this post](http://blog.macromates.com/2009/working-on-it/):

> ### Working on It
>
> Over the past two years, posts on this blog have slowed to just a trickle, and a number of TextMate users have asked about TextMate’s status, or publicly worried about its future. This blog post, the first I’ve written here in a long time, is an attempt to assuage those concerns and answer some of the most frequent questions.
>
> In short, TextMate development is going strong: TextMate 2 isn’t done yet, but progress is steady, it is starting to take shape, and the end is in sight. The rewrite has been a slow and careful process, but the ideas behind it are exciting. I hope to publicly describe some new abstractions in the coming weeks and months. Moreover, the community continues to churn out new bundles and features for TextMate 1.5, and I’ve been building up a backlog of posts describing them. While I am not writing to announce a release date for TextMate 2, I do hope that this post will be the first in a series showing a bit more transparency.
>
> The requests for TextMate 1 have mostly been incremental additions such as split views, chunked undo, and editing over SFTP. But TextMate 2 is about more than new surface features. Every part has been completely rewritten to take advantage of the lessons learned from the years of version 1. Not only are the low-level data structures chosen for increased flexibility, but the abstractions on which TextMate is built—snippets, scope-based language grammars, context-dependent settings—have been rethought and are more powerful than ever. In the coming months, I’ll try to describe some of these new abstractions, but for now, know that I am excited about the new ideas involved.
>
> So where does development stand for 2.0? It feels to me like most of the modules are getting close, say 90%. But as they say, on the horizon, mountains look small. While I use 2.0 for my own work, day-to-day, and the basic infrastructure is pretty solid, much of the front-end still needs work, and for now it’s all lacking the spit and polish of a finished app. Hopefully an alpha version will be ready before too long, but I can’t make any promises about dates.
>
> And why haven’t I been better about keeping the world informed? It is a combination of many things really, but the main issue is that I am not good at writing for a large audience. I am more into informal conversations, for instance over mailing lists or on IRC. So while I started a lot of posts, I end up unhappy with them halfway through, and they don’t get finished or published. I am taking measures: I have enlisted a technical writer to help bring this blog back to life, and I’ll try to communicate more of TextMate’s status and direction through him.
>
> Bigger than either of those problems though, as I mentioned, is that TextMate 2 is no minor facelift. It’s a major undertaking with a long timeline and its final form isn’t fully settled. I don’t want to hype vaporware, and I don’t want to get anyone’s hopes up before I know I can meet their expectations.
>
> Furthermore, I haven’t wanted to throw ideas onto the internet without having a chance to implement them myself. I’m humbled that TextMate has served as inspiration for many other products, and I hope that it continues to be a model for other developers in the future, but I want to see my ideas done my way first, before I feed them to the competition.
>
> I am trying to slowly turn this boat. With this post, I hopefully am showing that a hand is at the wheel. I know I’ve been quiet too long about my plans. I can’t make up for that, but going forward, I aim to do better.

And Here's the official blog post, saying the public alpha version will be release before Christmas 2011.
http://blog.macromates.com/2011/whats-next/

Answer (score 5):

Allan Odgaard (Oct 24, 2007):

> [...] there is no ETA, and I won’t speak
>   about timing before I am certain I can
>   provide an (alpha/beta) release within
>   the next month – because really, the
>   more I say, the more people ask, and
>   having to answer the same questions
>   over and over again is (for me)
>   mentally exhausting. So put TM 2.0 up
>   there with Duke Nukem Forever and be
>   positively surprised the day it is
>   released :)

Last I heard, it was in private alpha. Just remember: patience is a virtue. :)

Comment: sounds like he has moved on to other things...

Comment: release early and often, even if it's not ready. That's my take on it. Too much work has been done on products never released.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a [recent post on a mailing list](http://old.nabble.com/Re%3A-TM2-p28707277.html) from author Allan Odgaard.  It sheds a little light on the current state of development.

In short, don't expect anything soon.

Answer (score 2):

Well it's been 1 1/2 years since this question. And no update. And no news.

I'm moving on from textmate. Shame really, cause it was the best editor on Mac. But, hell, even dreamweaver has passed it up.

Comment: Maybe it's still the best editor.

Comment: Moving on? Why? Does TextMate have a half-life? Is it suddenly useless because it isn't getting new features every ten minutes?

Comment: No. it's useless cause it hasn't gotten new features in 3 years. Just a couple of minor bug fixes. There's a long list of missing features. I use BBedit now. But I do miss the color schemes of Textmate.

Comment: That's the point that I was making. If TextMate wasn't "useless" 3 years ago, why is it useless now? It's not like Vi is getting new "features" at a break-neck pace.

Answer (score 1):

> TextMate author was hired by MacRabbit (company behind the Espresso editor) so it could be that Espresso will be the next TextMate (it's a real shame..)

It doesn’t say that anywhere in the article. Besides, this is simply not true. MacRabbit is also a 1 person company like MacroMates. Textmate's developer lives in Denmark; MacRabbit's lives in Belgium.

Expresso is a different editor, not Textmate 2.

Answer (score 1):

I can scarcely believe this is true, but I just read that it is scheduled for release at the end of October, 2010.

http://wiki.macromates.com/FAQ/TextMate2

Comment: The wiki has been changed since this was posted, but i had verification from another source that I am not, in fact, completely mad.

Answer (score 0):

not exactly a direct answer to this question, but since I just signed up for an account and don't have the rep points to comment on an answer (or as it turns out include more than one hyperlink), I'll leave my response here for Paul and Vasil:

You should definitely check out Ciarán's [ReMate Update](http://ciaranwal.sh/2007/11/07/remate-update) plugin for TextMate as it has been invaluable for me while working with NFS.

I also highly recommend Ciarán's other TextMate plugin, ProjectPlus (ciaranwal.sh/projectplus)

One last plug for Ciarán...most likely due to the fact that he has developed some great plugins for TM1, he has also been hired by Allan (wiki.macromates.com/FAQ/TextMate2) to work on TextMate 2

Comment: > he has also been hired by Allan - That's fantastic I had no idea!  That guy's name is plastered across the TextMate/Mac ecosystem where ever I go, and it just drops off about 2 years ago.  Now it all makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

There's really no excuse in the world that could convince that textmate 2 isn't vaporware.

Even if he was secretly coding the editor to demolish all other editors, the amount of years that have passed and lack of any real evidence of anything solid whatsoever, point toward poor development practices and lack of experience producing a product.

Unfortunately it looks like textmate 1 was a fluke, and texmate 2 is the software worlds [chinese democracy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_Democracy)...

Comment: Or he's stoking his ego (not in a bad way at all! I love showing off awesome software I made) and the more suspense he builds the more rush he'll get for releasing it the yearning masses and blowing us all away.

Comment: it lives! https://github.com/textmate/textmate

Answer (score 0):

I think its sad that this question remains one of the top Google search items when looking for TextMate 2 information yet it is filled with rumors and insinuations.

**They are working diligently on it** and what they are trying to do is so very very hard.  Give them a break.  I even wrote an article on this: [On TextMate 2](http://hiltmon.blogspot.com/2011/07/on-textmate-2.html)

Answer (score 0):

A new post today with title [What's Next](http://blog.macromates.com/2011/whats-next/) on MacroMates official blog states (bold emphasis by me):

> There has been a lot of speculation and trepidation about the future of TextMate recently, mostly about whether there will be another major release. Work on 2.0 began and while we wish it could have been completed faster we are very pleased with how it is turning out. Development has reached a point finally where we can make an announcement:
>
> **There will be a public alpha release this year, before Christmas, for registered users.**

Answer (score -3):

I am predicting, right now, that he is going to surprise everyone and give us a gift on Christmas of this year.

How perfect of an opportunity would it be for him release a relatively polished non-beta on Christmas and watch everybody in the world go ape shit.

Mark my words.  10 days.

Comment: I could add something sarcastic. V1 is still serving me fine though.

Comment: Haha I figured if I'm wrong, no biggie.  If I happened to be right, I'd better have it posted somewhere and sound damn confident about it. ;)

Comment: Hey, looks I was just off by a year.  :)  I'm leavin' naysayers stumped like rainforests.

Answer (score -9):

TextMate author [was hired by MacRabbit](http://blog.olicio.us/2008/09/28/is-espresso-in-reality-textmate-2/) (company behind the Espresso editor) so it could be that Espresso will be the next TextMate (it's a real shame..)

Comment: Where does it say that Allan was hired by MacRabbit?

Comment: -1 that link says nothing worthwhile.